# Why are parentheses used in JOIN USING clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

From the following code example, why do I need to use parentheses () in the JOIN clauses, such as in  JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)?

I know that not using parentheses would return an error, but I would like to know how the machine reads this statement, per se.

```
SELECT 
Book_Title as 'Title',
Publisher_Name
FROM BOOK
JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)
JOIN WROTE USING (Book_Code)
JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num)
group by  Boo, k_Title, Publisher_Name
having count(distinct concat(LastName,FirstName)) = 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Avoid using `USING` and sleep well at night. The `USING` clause is obscure, error prone, and difficult to debug. For example: `JOIN AUTHOR USING (Author_Num)` is it joining against `BOOK`, against `PUBLISHER`, or against `WROTE`? No one knows...

Comment: *"USING is obscure, error prone, and costly/difficult to debug."* *"No one knows.."* @TheImpaler not sure what you mean as `BOOK
JOIN PUBLISHER USING (Publisher_Code)` is just a shorter way of writing `BOOK JOIN PUBLISHER ON BOOK.Publisher_Code = PUBLISHER.Publisher_Code`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why did you choose `PUBLISHER` there? It could be `BOOK`, or `WROTE`... `USING` is not at all clear when you have more than two tables.

Comment: *"Why did you choose PUBLISHER there? It could be BOOK, or WROTE... "* see comment update.. @TheImpaler

Comment: Also *"USING is obscure, error prone, and costly/difficult to debug."* @TheImpaler [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pXC3N8rLntmJsaCFqfCGmZ/0) proofs it's not costly as you have claimed both statements mean the same thing.. Notice the `SHOW WARNINGS;` output for both MySQL handles the rewrite/optimisation the same for both..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I value your opinion. Not to start a long discussion here, but please look at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n5mHoCUF4keFSjS4RFXsbJ/0 -- Shouldn't those two queries be equivalent? It's not that clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid ambiguity.  Let's say you did:

```
from a join
     b
     using c, d
```

SQL wouldn't know which of these you intend:

```
from a join
     b
     using (c, d)
```

or:

```
from a join
     b
     using c cross join
     d
```

Hence, the standard requires parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is part of ISO and it was defined that way:

> [Lexical elements - BNF](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2008-foundation-grammar.html#named-columns-join)
>
> ```
> <named columns join> ::=
> USING <left paren> <join column list> <right paren>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `Table1 JOIN Table2 ON <expr>` accepts any expression following `ON`. The expression can include comparisons and boolean terms. Expressions are not required to have parentheses.

The syntax of `Table1 JOIN Table2 USING (<column-list>)` does not accept an expression, it only accepts a *tuple* with is a list of columns inside parentheses. It's understood that this is logically equivalent to a series of boolean terms separated by `AND` where each term compares the column of the same name in both tables.

```
Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ColumnA = Table2.ColumnA
                  AND Table1.ColumnB = Table2.ColumnB
```

Is the same as

```
Table1 JOIN Table2 USING (ColumnA, ColumnB)
```

But it's also the same as an expression with a *tuple comparison*:

```
Table1 JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.ColumnA, Table1.ColumnB) = (Table2.ColumnA, Table2.ColumnB)
```

Tuple comparisons do require parentheses to make the operator precedence clear.

Now that we've seen tuple comparisons, the `USING` syntax looks more like a shortened version of that. It's for a tuple of column names without table qualifiers.

Comment: As a general rule it's better to avoid `USING` because of its obscurity. It doesn't specify which tables the columns are coming from. For example: `USING (ColumnA, ColumnB)` ... does it translate to `(Table1.ColumnA, Table1.ColumnB) = (Table2.ColumnA, Table2.ColumnB)` or `(Table3.ColumnA, Table3.ColumnB) = (Table2.ColumnA, Table2.ColumnB)` ?

Comment: *" It doesn't specify which tables the columns are coming from"* @TheImpaler the SQL standards clearly defines the scope/syntax rules which table references `USING()` should be operating on.. *"As a general rule it's better to avoid USING because of its obscurity. "* That i can agree on the "syntax sugar" might make it (bit) harder to understand for people that not know how `USING()` works